# On the finite limit of a product of real functions, one of then being unbounded

Tags: calculus, limits

Given functions $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x).g(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x) = \infty$, is it true that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ by force? If so, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contradiction $f$ does not converge to $0$ around $+\infty$. By definition, this means that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all $A > 0$ there is $x_A > A$ such that $\lvert f(x) \rvert > \epsilon$.

In particular (taking $A=1$, then $2$, then $3$, etc), there exists a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 1}$ such that $\lvert f(x_n) \rvert > \epsilon$ for all $n$, but $x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$.

Since $\lim_\infty g = \infty$, however, $g(x_n)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$. Thus $\vert f(x_n)g(x_n)\rvert > \epsilon\lvert g(x_n)\rvert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \infty$, contradicting the assumption that $\lim_\infty fg = 1$.

Comment: I think that you meant ... |f(x_{A})| > \epsilon. at the end of the first paragraph. But you have provided the answer I was looking for. Thank you.